# I get the "The resource you are looking for has been removed " when using OleDbConnection connection

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, azure, azure-webapps

I have a web application with the following code below, when I run the function below on my local machine everything works fine, but when i run from the web app in azure thats its publish in I get the error "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

The folder names "Files" is created in web app, I can check that the files upload are being created and stored there temporarily, but i still get the error. from troubleshooting it seems to come from when connections is being called to open

```
{
            string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath);
            //get the strig data from fileupload asp

            //Get the property f the extensions
            string ExcelString = string.Empty;
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

            switch (extension)
            {

                case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                    //ExcelString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                    ExcelString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'";

                    FileGood = true;
                    break;
                case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher
                              //ExcelString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;

                    ExcelString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'";
                    FileGood = true;
                    break;

            }

            ExcelString = string.Format(ExcelString, excelPath);

           
            //making query  
            string query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]";


            StatusLabel.Text = ExcelString;
            //Providing connection  
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ExcelString);

            Console.Write(ExcelString);
            
            //checking that connection state is closed or not if closed the   
            //open the connection  
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
              conn.Open(); //ERROR Caused FROM HERE
            }

            
            //create command object  
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
            // create a data adapter and get the data into dataadapter  
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            //fill the Excel data to data set  
            da.Fill(ds);
            //set data source of the grid view  
            PopGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            //binding the gridview  
            PopGrid.DataBind();
            //close the connection  

               
            conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing error?

Comment: seems to be from this " conn.Open(); "

Comment: Is the `ExcelString` correct? Are you able to check the data using `ExcelString`?

Comment: yeah, i checked the excelstring, it points to where upload file is in web app environment

Comment: Are you able to connect to that database? Pls try once

Comment: am not sure has an error occurs when  I try to open the connection

Comment: Is there an error while opening db through connection string? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Am a novice with c# OleDbConnection is used to help read excel spreadsheet which is the desired upload file, to read the data inside so we can create a datatable from it. but whn I try to open connection I get the server error 404. but it works fine when i run it from the local machine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228409/discussion-between-singhh-msft-and-ola-owo).